# How to onclick parts of a stacked svg image

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have built up an image using several svg files so that I have control over swapping parts of the image & changing colors.

I'm now looking at why I can't mouse click anything other than the top svg item. I assumed it was because my image was oversized, but I've corrected that. The images are placed using the embed tag and I've also tried altering the embed height and width attributes.

Can I even do this? Or should I be looking for a different solution.

** Edit **
I added code, but have removed it as it wasn't used by those offering help and didn't contribute to the solution.

Comment: Please show us the code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Check the DOM inspector on your web browser 10 to 1 odds say that while your image might be a circle, the embed element is a square.

Comment: It could also be that with the layering, if the shapes are filled with a color, the mouseclicks register with which ever filled shape is "on top" and won't connect with the shapes underneath.  Might be worth some trial and error if you haven't already.  I agree with Robert, let's see your code and let us dive in.

Comment: @Robert I'm still getting the hang of this forum, I posted some code here a couple of days ago for you to take a look at, but didn't post a comment to that effect. Might be the reason its gone unnoticed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I adopted was to use a clear overlay image plus an image map.

For details, please refer to;
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830786/to-enable-clicking-on-layered-svg-images/13849060#13849060)